# angular-dialog-service $injector:modulerr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using 5.2.11 of https://github.com/m-e-conroy/angular-dialog-service/tree/v5.2.11

Angular 1.4.8

I'm adding ui.bootstrap and dialogs.main to my app file:

```
var FuelTeamworkHelperApp = angular.module( "FuelTeamworkHelperApp", [ "ui.bootstrap", "dialogs.main", "ui.router", "ncy-angular-breadcrumb", "ngResource", "angular-loading-bar", "ngAnimate", "angular-growl", "ngPrettyJson", "angularMoment" ] );
```

However, I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=FuelTeamworkHelperA…alhost%3A2804%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)
```

Scripts are all definitely in the HTML and browser is loading them.

I tried using 'dialogs.controllers' which works, though according to the documentation that's not how you're meant to use it..!

Not sure how to then get it into my controllers either, which name I should be using? Just 'dialogs' doesn't work.

```
angular
    .module( "FuelTeamworkHelperApp" )
    .controller( "AdminSettingsController", AdminSettingsController );

//---

AdminSettingsController.$inject = [ "$scope", "$rootScope", "$state", "$stateParams", "$filter", "$resource", "$q", "growl", "dialogs", "FuelTeamworkHelperConfig", "AppSettings", "SowCustomListSections" ];

function AdminSettingsController ( $scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $filter, $resource, $q, growl, dialogs, FuelTeamworkHelperConfig, AppSettings, SowCustomListSections ) {
```

...

Comment: Did you include the module ngSanitize with your project? I'm looking at the source code in main and it lists it as a dependency (this isn't a dependancy for the controllers which is probably why its working).

Also in the documentation under notes it says: For version 2.0 + of this service module do not forget to include the ngSanitize Angular module.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular-sanitize.min.js    https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

Comment: Ah, I totally missed that in the docs... way way down on the page. I'll have to try it tomorrow, but I'm guessing this will probably be it. Thanks for the direction! Will report back tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to this (as commented by Mike) was the need to include the dependancy ngSanitize.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.min.js

[docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize)